# Unable to compile wxWidgets with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets, codeblocks, include-path

I am unable to compile wxWidgets with gcc in Code::Blocks. I did everything according to the documentation on the wxWidgets site:

1. I downloaded wx correctly
2. I compiled correctly according to the documentation guidelines
3. I set everything in Code::Blocks according to guide

Everthing went well until I wrote a program in Code::Blocks and clicked the compile button.  About 30 - 40 errors are displayed, including:

> wx/wx.h not found

and dozens of undeclared error

I compiled the hello world program from the official site. I think there's a problem in the make file or the library. Any solution?

Comment: Was [this guide](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxWindowsQuickRef) the one you used? Did you use the "wxPack" or wxWidgets sources? Are you using MinGW or MSVC? This issue is one of "include paths" so you'll have to make sure the compiler has the path added for wherever the parent directory of `wx/wx.h` is, although it sounds like there's lots of "wizards" involved here and if they aren't doing the magic for you then it may be harder to fix than it should be.  *(Also, I'd petition you to use [Qt and Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) instead...far better.)*

Comment: Additionally, what platform are you on?  (I assumed Windows because that's the guide I found.)  Also: How did you create your makefile?  Did you use the wizard and choose "new wxWidgets app" or use a makefile you got from somewhere else?  If you didn't use the wizard, try that and see if the boilerplate it generates will compile properly.  *(Or, again, forget this clunky thing and use Qt. :P)*

Comment: @HostileFork yes i used the guide you listed...generally my internet down speed is like 10kBps so unable to download wxpack....I download short wxwidget and also do everthing you listed......But still the errors are same.....any sol..or automatic batch script or something like that

Comment: @HostileFork i create Make file using mingw32-make.exe and some switches .......Platform is window........

Comment: Sorry to hear about your slow internet :-/ you might want to pack up your laptop (or USB thumb drive) and head to a library or somewhere to do big downloads. In any case, I don't use these tools and keep pushing Qt Creator whether you want it or not. But I've retagged your question to attract the right attention. If you include your makefiles and command line in your question (note the "edit" button) it will provide more information to anyone looking for clues as to why your include path isn't set correctly. But that is the thing you are looking to have set properly: the "include path"...

Comment: @HostileFork did cmake solve my problem.....i heared about cmake it install many library without any prob..what you think

Comment: CMake is nothing special, although it's better than [autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) and friends.  But I bet you can get to the bottom of your problem without it.  Dig deeper into what I'm telling you...find `wx.h` on your system and then if you find that it is underneath `C:/foo/bar/wx/wx.h` then you  need to make sure `C:/foo/bar` is in your include path...so the compiler finds `wx/wx.h`.  Understand?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add wxWidgets you downloaded and built to your compiler include path.

For example my wxWidgets is located at: C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\

In build options for your project, go to the **Search directories**-tab and in the **Compiler**-subtab you can add your search path for the include directory in your wxWidgets location, in my example that would be: **C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include**